# mongodb ORMs without full schema?

Tags: java, mongodb, scala

I'm frequently finding myself with one foot in POJO land, and one foot in JSON land.
I want my Mongo documents that have a formal, but partially specified schema. POJO land assumes a fully specified schema. JSON land provides no contraints.

As an example, suppose I download a bunch of user data from facebook, it arrives as a JSON blob. Facebook essentially owns this structure and its madness to try to map it into an internal POJO structure - if one days FB changes this, our server break and we stop collecting this data, what the right thing to do is to store it verbatim.

What I want is to specify rules and contraints about what goes into all my databases *to the extent possible and the schema is well defined*:

- this attribute should be a long
- this attribute needs to be encrypted
- this attribute is optional
- this object can have an number of additional extra fields
  ...

I'm half way through building such a thing. But though it would be a good idea to see if existing project exist that allow document constraints to be specified.

Comment: Why is this tagged as scala?

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is called a object-document-mapper or ODM (the document-database analogue to an ORM, or object-relational mapper in SQL databases).

There are different wrappers like this available for Java, like [Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) or [Spring-MongoDB](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/). A longer list can be found on [Java Language Center on mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/).

Comment: Thanks. Will update the question.
Where most ORM falls flat is that they assume a fully specified schema that can be mapped into concrete POJO, instead of more abstract and flexible list and map-like structure -- they're ignore the weak schema benefits of NOSQL databases.